# Cloudkit returning records with a specific string

Tags: ios, arrays, nspredicate, cloudkit, ckquery

In my project, with a CloudKit Record Type "User"(I've tested with other Record Type names too) I create a record with an email field.

I'm trying to match that email exactly and fetch records that match. I am doing this with an IN or == predicate, (for single or list of emails).

```
let query = CKQuery(recordType: "User", predicate: NSPredicate(format: "email IN %@", emails))
let query = CKQuery(recordType: "User", predicate: NSPredicate(format: "email == %@", "julio_ukohgsp_chevez@tfbnw.net"))
```

The email I'm having issues with is "julio_ukohgsp_chevez@tfbnw.net", any attempt to retrieve a record with this email returns 0, however if I change it to "julio_ukohgsp_chevez@tfbnw.ne" it will retrieve OK.

Initially I assumed it was the special characters, but other strings with them work fine. Then I assume length, but other longer strings work fine.

Does anyone else have this issue? I'm having a hard time trusting CloudKit without understanding why it's not able to match this string.

I asked a similar question, but before I had the details, a user was able to test this and got the same results with this string. This post is a lot more concise and has steps to recreate.

Comment: Are you saying that if you change the predicate to `"email == %@", "julio_ukohgsp_chevez@tfbnw.ne"` (no `t`), then you get back the expected result? If that's the case, then are you *really* sure that the value in the database isn't actually `julio_ukohgsp_chevez@tfbnw.ne`?

Comment: Yep, I'm 100% sure. It's bizarre.  I've checked many times and typed it in manually. I can try your specific string, but even replacing any 1 character has worked.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. Have you found anything about this?

Comment: Yes! I started encoding the email strings using escapes and Unicode character numbers. If I display them I just have to decode them first. Credit: https://disqus.com/home/discussion/hackingwithswift/reading_from_icloud_with_cloudkit_ckqueryoperation_and_nspredicate/?utm_source=reply&utm_medium=email&utm_content=read_more#comment-2690767407

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
let predicateString = "email IN '\(emails)'"
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: predicateString)
```